# Atom linter-gcc doesn't work with multiple files

Tags: c++, c, atom-editor, linter

Hellow. I have test project with two .c and one .h files. And in this case linter-gcc doesn't see header file.

```
/* main.c */
#include "module.h"

int main()
{
  f(5);
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
/* module.h */
#ifndef HELLOW
#define HELLOW

void f(int a);

#endif
```

---

```
/* module.c */
#include "module.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int a)
{
  printf("i\n", a);
}
```

---

```
/* CMakeLists.txt is */
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(calc-2.4.0)
set(SOURCE_EXE main.c header.c header.h)
add_definitions(-Wall)
add_executable(calc ${SOURCE_EXE})
```

---

```
/* .gcc-flags.json */
{
  "execPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
  "gccDefaultCFlags": "-Wall -c",
  "gccDefaultCppFlags": "-Wall -std=c++11",
  "gccErrorLimit": 15,
  "gccIncludePaths": "..,.,./include,./path",
  "gccSuppressWarnings": true
}
```

Errors that I see

```
Error   GCC module.h: No such file or directory 1:10    main.c
Error   GCC module.h: No such file or directory 1:10    module.c
```

I also can't make lib from .c .h because in real project I have a lot of cross dependences between files. What shall I do to make linter work? Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your IDE, paste the text of code and output and compiler error on your question.

Comment: Are all these files placed in the same directory? Try to change #include statement to `#include <module.h>`.

Comment: So, I made an error on my answer, that's why I deleted it (so that I can fixed it). I recreated your setup and cmake was able to compile everything. So the question is, are the `.c` files and the `.h` files all in the same directory? What happens when you execute just this `gcc -c main.c -o main.o`? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory. I can compile this project successfully, but ptoblem is in the file compile_commands.json that I get by cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 and linter-gcc in atom can't find .h file.